# How do I revert this change in MacOS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, amazon-workspaces

Previously I made this change in MacOS Terminal to switch functionality of the command and control key inside Amazon Workspace

`defaults write "com.amazon.Amazon WorkSpaces Client" remap_cmd_to_ctrl 0`

please can someone help me now, what should I enter in terminal to revert the ctrl and cmd keys to their original default?

I tried reversing the instruction like this below, but it didn't work and it says defaults are unchanged

```
`defaults write "com.amazon.Amazon WorkSpaces Client" remap_ctrl_to_cmd 0`
```

2024-01-11 13:28:43.889 defaults[3738:4285221] Unexpected argument write; leaving defaults unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

`defaults write "com.amazon.Amazon WorkSpaces Client" remap_cmd_to_ctrl`

should disable it.